# Protobuffers to XML

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to convert my google protocol object to XML format. In that I would like to keep some fields as attribute. 
Instead of :

```
<field>
    <name>ApiFieldHeaderName</name>
    <maxLength>50</maxLength>
</field>
```

I want following :

```
<field name="ApiFieldHeaderName" maxLength="50" ></field>
```

My protocol is

```
string name = 1;
int32 maxLength = 2;
```

And then I have gone through some forum and used **xml_disposition**

```
[(xml_disposition) = ATTRIBUTE]
```

However, I am getting the error:

> Option "(xml_disposition)" unknown.

I am using proto3 and language is Java.

```
syntax = "proto3";
option optimize_for = SPEED;
```

Comment: The xml_disposition - is that something you've edited into the Java? Or is that in the .proto schema? Can you show exactly how you've used it, in context?

Comment: @MarcGravell I have used [(xml_disposition) = ATTRIBUTE]
 in .proto schema.

string name = 1 [(xml_disposition) = ATTRIBUTE];

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've found `xml_disposition` from a side discussion on the protobuf newsgroup from 2009. The option mentioned, however, was purely hypothetical. As far as I know: no such `xml_disposition` custom option exists - and least, not as a standard option - and no code-generator looks for it. No mention of `xml_disposition` exists in the Google protobuf source, and the current version of `protoc` (3.5.1) does not recognise it and an inbuilt option.

So:

- yes, it is possible to add custom extensions in .proto that you can annotate fields (etc) with
- yes, you can write your own codegen tools to check for those custom options and emit additional *generated* code to implement what you want
- but none of this ships by default

Side note: custom options must be defined in "proto2" syntax files, but a "proto3" file can still import and use those custom options from the "proto2" file.

Comment: So xml_disposition can be achieved through  proto2. Am I correct? Correct me if I am wrong.